# Recognize Hand Getsures in Android

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

Is there any way to detect hand gestures (wave of hand towards right/left/up/down) using front camera in Android mobiles 
I have tried the link http://www.nanocritical.com/nanogest/api/android.html>
But its API is not available on this link or anywhere.I just need to identify WAVE movement of hand in 4 directions so as to implement page navigation & scrolling features.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution to recognise hand movements(wave of hand towards right/left/up/down) from [this](https://github.com/kritts/HandWave) link
I found this useful.